# string concatenation appends to beginning instead of the end

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I need to check if the last char of the line is a `/` if not add one.
I'm able to go through the ident process to look if the last character is `/`
but when I concatenate the `/` to a string, it appears at the beginning of the line and not at the end. Can't find a hint why it's happening.
I have this code:

```
for x in file:
    x= x.rstrip('\n') #deleting cr at eol
    xx=len(x)
    if x[xx-2:xx-1] != ("/"):
        x=x[:xx]+"/" # nor this one is working x=x+"/"
```

This adds `/` to beginning of the file.

Getting the same thing in this peace  url = add+x+page+yas, I have page added at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add a path separator (`'/'` on unix):

```
for x in file:
    x = os.path.join(x.rstrip(), '')
```

And of course you'll have to add `import os` or `from os import path` at the start of your code.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I would like to understand why the concatenation appends in wrong place

Comment: Sorry, but your code works on my pc if I replace `x[xx-2:xx-1]` with `x[xx-1:xx]`. And anyway, it's best to utilize python library functions than use a C-style low-level method.

Comment: any clues with this  url = add+x+page+yas I'm getting the the page added at the beginning!